# Efficient array storage

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace, storage

I have a large (300,000 rows by 25 columns) array which I read in

```
dataset = numpy.genfromtxt(DataFileName,dtype="string",delimiter=',')
```

and then clean up the newlines and quote. I tried doing this in two ways:

**1st way of cleaning up**

```
for i in range(len(dataset)): 
    for j in range(len(dataset[i])):
        dataset[i][j] = dataset[i][j].replace("\n", "").replace("\"", "")
```

**2nd way of cleaning up**

```
dataset = [ [word.replace('\n','').replace('"','') for word in dataset[i]] for i in range(len(dataset))]
```

Following this, I do some intensive searching of the array to compute a bunch of things. The search is *5 times faster* if I do the cleaning up with second way rather than the first way. What is the reason?

Comment: Woah, pretty curious indeed. Well, the two main difference I see is that in the second case you use and iterator and you copy the elements in a new list instead of updating in place. Have you tried using `[[word... for word in row] for row in dataset]` instead of `for i in ...` in the second?

Comment: As Laurent points out, in one case you are searching a numpy array, in the other a list. If in your second case you wrapped all the right hand side in a `numpy.array(...)` you should get the exact same result as in the first case. From your experience, you don't want to do that, because it seems lists are more efficient than arrays for the job you are doing. Also, `genfromtext` lets you define `converters` functions that can do the clean up while the data is being read, see the docs for details: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: How can we tell why the search is faster in the second case if you do not show us how you are searching?
+1 to Jaime. I was going to write about that now. I'd point out that numpy is good when you have *numerical* data to handle. In most other cases it's simply slower than pure python solutions(and this usually includes also arbitrary-big integer arithmetic)

Comment: The data elements (being searched, processed, etc.) are currently all being operated on as strings -- although it's all numbers so conceivably using converters to clean up the data when it's being read in using genfromtext will help.

Comment: Could you provide a few rows of your data, and outline the operations you run on them after doing the clean up?

Comment: The large dataset is composed of ~300,000 rows such as "09","61978","6103527","0000",2012,1,"C",0,798,793,793,8,"7",256,243,"94.9","401.4","55","31","86","13","1","0",243, if the first three elements are non-zero, then these elements are compared with two other datasets (10,000 x 10 elements and 1,200 x 4 elements respectively) to extract selected fields from the second and third datasets. So the p-code would be for row in dataset, if valid (non-zero) then find corresponding rows in second & third sets, extract elements and print.

Answer (score 0):

In general, list comprehension (the second way) is faster than the for loop. I forgot the reason for it.

Also, if your have a large data set, using xrange() is faster than range() because xrange() returns a small generator, which generates data on the fly. Whereas range() returns the whole list [0 .. 300,000].

Finally, you should consider doing away with range(), xrange() altogether:

```
dataset = [[word.replace('\n','').replace('"','') for word in line] for line in dataset]
```

Doing it this way is cleaner and should be faster, because you don't deal with array subscription, which takes time.